# Simple CART model example

Tags: decision-trees, cart

My goal is to test Decision tree to regression model.
My data is like below(python dataframe). There are 2 features F1 and F2. And there is label which is number.
How to make CART model from this using sklearn or Tensorflow?
(I've searched the examples but they look complex for beginner like me.)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Dataframe({'F1',[a,a,b,b],'F2',[a,b,a,b],'Label',[10,20,100,200]})

F1 F2 label
a  a  10
a  b  20
b  a  100
b  b  200
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `sklearn` [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html) it is stated that:

> scikit-learn uses an optimised version of the CART algorithm; however,
> scikit-learn implementation does not support categorical variables for
> now.

So you could use [sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html)

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
X, y = load_diabetes(return_X_y=True)
regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=0)
cross_val_score(regressor, X, y, cv=10)
```

There is also a [TF implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/decision_forests/api_docs/python/tfdf/keras/CartModel).

```
import tensorflow_decision_forests as tfdf
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv("project/dataset.csv")
tf_dataset = tfdf.keras.pd_dataframe_to_tf_dataset(dataset, label="my_label")

model = tfdf.keras.CartModel()
model.fit(tf_dataset)

print(model.summary())
```